# Inspection "Non-reclaimed resource acquisition" in resharper C++

Tags: c++, resharper

I write a c++ program using VS2015 with ReSharper C++ and I encountered the following inspection:
[image]

can someone please explain me why does this inspection jumps up?
I believe that it is not something too critical, but I still would like to know.

here's the relevant code snippet:

```
void allocate2DArr(char** arr, int rows, int cols)
{
    arr = new char *[rows];
    for (auto i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = new char[cols];
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: Why are you using raw pointers and new in this instance? Using smart pointers (`unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` depending on your needs) should really by your default choice unless you have some justifiable need to use raw pointers. See https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/30/gotw-90-solution-factories/ ...or as one of the answers point to, why are you not using a `std::vector<std::vector<char>>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`arr` is not returned or declared with sufficient indirection to be passed by reference. End result is when `arr` goes out of scope the allocation is lost.

But `arr` is a pointer, you say? Indeed it is, but you modify the the pointer itself, and this requires the pointer to be passed by reference to have any effect back at the calling function. At the end of the day, a pointer is just another variable. Pass it into the function and the function operates on a local copy.

In this case, `arr` is a copy of the variable passed by the caller. Both `arr` and the original point to the same place, but as soon as you `arr = new char *[rows];`, `arr` points to a different location and the original is none the wiser. This is just like passing in an `int`, say 100, into a function. Initially the caller an the called agree on 100, but what happens in the function stays in the function.

Solution: Pass by reference.

```
void allocate2DArr(char** & arr, int rows, int cols)
```

Alternative 1: Return the created array

```
char** allocate2DArr(int rows, int cols)
```

Alternative 2: Use `std::vector`, `std::unique_ptr`, or a smart wrapper class around the `char**` to handle the memory management and still allow access to the `char**` when calling a legacy interface.

Comment: thanks for the answer. as I mentioned in another comment to an answer, he interface I'm working with is forcing me to use `char **`, so `std::vector` is not an option here. why do I have to pass `are` as a reference so it would change? do you mean that when I perform the `new[]` operation the pointer I am passing is being changed?

Comment: @noamgot `arr` is a copy of the variable passed by the caller. Both `arr` and the original point to the same place, but as soon as you `arr = new char *[rows];`, `arr` points to a different location and the original is none the wiser. This is just like passing in an `int`, say 100, into a function. initially the caller an the called agree on 100, but what happens in the function stays in the function.

Comment: I have another question - when I want to `delete[]` the array (with a similar function for deleting it, i.e first iterating and `delete[]`ing `arr[i]`, and then `delete[] arr`) - will I have to pass it by reference (i.e `void deleteArr(char**& arr)`), or passing by value (i.e `void deleteArr(char** arr)`) would do? @user4581301

Comment: Here passing by value works because the target is the pointed-at address. As an alternative, consider making an [RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) and [Rule of Five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) compliant wrapper class to manage the allocation and de-allocation for you.

Answer (score 2):

> can someone please explain me why does this inspection jumps up?

Because you *acquired* (allocated) *resources* (memory in particular), that you did not *reclaim* (deallocate) in *some* (actually all that enter the function) code paths.

> I believe that it is not something too critical, but I still would like to know.

Depends a bit on type of the program. Memory leaks are never nice, but they are certainly critical in long running software like servers and daemons.

Solution: Always `delete[]` what you `new[]`. Better yet: Never `new[]` but use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: thanks. unfortunately ,the interface I'm working with is forcing me to use `char **`... and of course I will `delete[]` it, there's a similar function for that

Comment: @noamgot That's unfortunate indeed (although it technically doesn't prevent you from using a vector, but it does make the use of a vector a bit complicated). Anyway, you cannot `delete[]` a pointer that is local to `allocate2DArr` in another function unless you somehow copy the local pointer to outside. Perhaps you intended to return it?

Comment: I played with it a bit more and I now understand what you meant. I guess that allocating a local variable and returning it would be the right choice. thanks!